# Chef overriding attributes from another recipe in same cookbook

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a cookbook with 2 recipes.

attributes/default.rb

`default['vpn']['crt'] = 'nocrt'`

The default recipe has a file resource that creates a generic crt file

```
file 'cert' do
    path "/etc/vpn/#{node.default['network']['hostname']}.crt"
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode '0644'
    content node.default['vpn']['crt']
end
```

In the second recipe `client.rb`, I include the default recipe, load an encrypted data bag for that "client" and override the attribute. BUT it doesn't get overridden.

```
include_recipe 'my-cookbook'

vault = ChefVault::Item.load('auth', 'client')

node.override['vpn']['crt'] = vault['crt']

...
```

The file's content == 'nocrt'

According to [Chef's Attribute Precedence](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html), it should override with the content of `vault['crt']`.

**UPDATE:**

Javier Cortejoso: Your answer works when used in the file resource.

But consider this for example:

attributes/default.rb:

```
default['network']['hostname'] = 'generic-host-name'
```

In recipes/default.rb:

```
Chef::Log.info(node['network']['hostname'])
Chef::Log.info(node.default['network']['hostname'])
Chef::Log.info(node.override['network']['hostname'])
```

In recipes/client.rb:

```
node.override['network']['hostname'] = 'client-host-name'
include_recipe 'cookbook::default'
```

So even if even I change the order of execution to the client.rb recipe first, then default.rb after overriding, it still gives me the hostname 'generic-host-name':

```
==> default: [2015-03-04T17:30:43+00:00] INFO: generic-host-name
==> default: [2015-03-04T17:30:43+00:00] INFO: generic-host-name
==> default: [2015-03-04T17:30:43+00:00] INFO: {}
```

**SOLUTION**

I'm a ****in idiot. I had both of these in my Vagrant file:

```
chef.add_role "cookbook"
chef.add_recipe "cookbook::client"
```

Thanks Javier Cortejoso for pointing clarifying the lazy attribute loading for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO It seems that the attribute is overridden after the compilation `file['cert']`. It a "time" problem and not a "priority" problem. There are some points you may take care in order to get correct order of execution of your recipes:

- The order of execution should be running first the recipe where you override the attribute (`client.rb`), and later the recipe where you use the overridden attribute (`default.rb`).
- You can also use the [lazy attribute evaluation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#lazy-attribute-evaluation) for your attribute with the content.

So your `default.rb` should be:

```
    include_recipe 'my-cookbook::client'
    file 'cert' do
        path "/etc/vpn/#{node.default['network']['hostname']}.crt"
        owner 'root'
        group 'root'
        mode '0644'
        content lazy node.default['vpn']['crt']
    end
```

Comment: Thanks for the lazy attributes link, it was helpful but there are still issues. I've updated my question.